# __getitem__ for multiple attributes of a single class

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, swig

I have a Python wrapped api that I am working on that I am using swig to generate an interface for, and I need to find a way to use the Python built in function `__getitem__` for different components of the class.

A simple case is:

```
obj = module.class()

for i in range(obj.numPart1()):
    print (obj.part1[i])

for i in range(obj.numPart2()):
    print (obj.part2[i])
```

If this is totally wrong and there is a more 'Pythonic' way to do this, I am all ears. The base object must have two parts though, since it is a triangulation with access to vertices and facets all associated to the same C++ backend.

---

I have looked around in quite a few places, and I have tried usage of `metaclasses` and the `super` functions in Python and have had no luck mostly because of how my classes are laid out because of SWIG. I also may not be understanding them fully as well...

If need be, I even can add items to the C++ side if I need to to be able to give what is needed, but I want to end up with a single class that can access either one of two attributes the object has that are essentially lists. Adding to the C++ side is less ideal since the code is re-used elsewhere so I would like to minimize messing with the C++ code if possible.

Using SWIG causes a couple of problems I should mention

- `__init__` cannot be modified since it is generated in SWIG. I can only add to the class
- Any Python code I put in must be either in an existing class or at the top of the file. (I can't add classes anywhere in the file).

---

Below is what I would like the access to look like with a somewhat representative code sample:

NOTE: All functions in this example are wrapped C++ functions except for the wrapped built-in functions (`__getitem__`,`__enter__`,`__exit__`)

```
import ModTest as m

with m.multiAttrObj() as obj:
   print ("Attribute A:")
   for i in range(obj.nAttrA()):
      #print (obj.getAttrA(i))  # This version works
      print (obj.AttrA[i])      # This version fails

   print ("\nAttribute B:")
   for i in range(obj.nAttrB()):
      #print (obj.getAttrB(i))  # This version works
      print (obj.AttrB[i])      # This version fails
```

And my module would look roughly like this:

```
#ModTest.py
class multiAttrObj():
   # Init method cannot be changed...generated by SWIG (in real case)
   def __init__(self):
      # Real module attributes are actually an instance of a C++ object
      self._attrA = "a b c d e f".split()
      self._attrB = "1 2 3 4 5".split()

   def __enter__(self):
      self.__init__
      return self

   def __exit__(self, a,b,c):
      self._attrA = None
      self._attrB = None

   def nAttrA(self):
      return len(self._attrA)

   def nAttrB(self):
      return len(self._attrB)

   # Only way to get to AttrA from Python, calls C++ accessor
   def getAttrA(self,i):
      # real return is as below:
      # return _multiAttrObj.get_attr_a(i)
      return self._attrA[i]  # Example for testing without .pyd

   # Only way to get to AttrB from Python, calls C++ accessor
   def getAttrB(self,i):
      # real return is as below:
      # return _multiAttrObj.get_attr_b(i)
      return self._attrB[i]  # Example for testing without .pyd

   # Function can be created, but throws 
   # TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
   # when called like __getitem__
   #def AttrA(self,i):
   #   return self._attrA[i]

   #def AttrB(self,i):
   #   return self._attrB[i]

   def __getitem__(self,i):
      # This can't distiguish which attribute I want.
      pass
```

EDIT:
**ANSWER**

Revising the solution from martineau, I used the provided Sequence proxy, and stuck with attributes for the sake of SWIG since I can't re-map `__getattr__` or `__setattr__`. Answer snippet below:

```
def _getAttrAWrap(self):
    return SequenceProxy(self.getAttrA, self.nAttrA)

def _getAttrBWrap(self):
    return SequenceProxy(self.getAttrB, self.nAttrB)

# Missing setter functions are for future use.
AttrA = property(_getAttrAWrap, "")
AttrB = property(_getAttrBWrap, "")
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Can you post the actual stack trace for the exception in question?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can (and should) have SWIG handle this for you.

Comment: @TemporalWolf: What exception? This question doesn't involve any exceptions.

Comment: @ user2357112 `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable when called like __getitem__`

Comment: @TemporalWolf: Ah, it was buried in code comments.

Comment: Can't you get SWIG to just publically expose `_attrA` and `_attrB` as `attrA` and `attrB`? Messing with `__getitem__` is the wrong way to go.

Comment: I am cheating here since it is a list, but in the real case it has more depth. I am using getitem so I can call the getAttr functions that call the accessors on the C++ side. I'll add a comment to the code to make that more obvious.
SWIG won't handle it mainly because I can't overload the operator[] from C++ so I have to re-map it in Python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit #2.1** (after tweaking Edit #2 slightly)

The key to solving this problem is realizing that what is needed is a way to override the indexing (via the `__getitem__()` method) of the ***attributes*** of the class, not of the outermost container class itself.

To do this, here's a more streamlined, in the sense that it not longer uses properties, and therefore likely faster version of the first revision of my original answer (aka **Edit #1**). Instead of them it implements a `__getattr__()` method which will be normally only be called once, when attribute `AttrA` or `AttrB` is referenced but don't exist yet. From that point on it won't be called again. This works around the problem of not being able to change the class `__init__()` method generated by SWIG (but doesn't limit the class to being used as a context manager (although but still supports being used as one).

These two attributes, when created, will be instances of a new concrete subclass named `SequenceProxy` derived from the `collections.Sequence` abstract base class. This class is similar a regular `list` except its custom `__getitem__()` method calls a function that was provide to its constructor when it was created. Similarly, a different provided function will be called to determine and return its length when requested.

Using `SequenceProxy` instances provides a chance to forward any indexing and length query calls on to any functions or bound methods you choose—thus providing the "hooks" or "bottlenecks" needed to to make it happen.

```
import collections

class SequenceProxy(collections.Sequence):
    """Proxy class to make something appear to be an (immutable) sized iterable
       container based on just the two functions (or bound methods) provided to
       the constructor.
    """
    def __init__(self, item_getter, length_getter):
        self._item_getter = item_getter
        self._get_length = length_getter

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._item_getter(index)

    def __len__(self):
        return self._get_length()

class multiAttrObj():
    # Init method cannot be changed...generated by SWIG (in real case)
    def __init__(self):
        self._attrA = "a b c d e f".split()
        self._attrB = "1 2 3 4 5".split()

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """This will create AttrA or AttrB when they are first referenced."""
        if name == 'AttrA':
            self.AttrA = SequenceProxy(self.getAttrA, self.nAttrA)
            return self.AttrA
        elif name == 'AttrB':
            self.AttrB = SequenceProxy(self.getAttrB, self.nAttrB)
            return self.AttrB
        else:
            raise AttributeError('{!r} is not an attribute of {}'.format(
                    name, self.__class__.__name__))

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        pass # will implicitly return None which mean handle exceptions normally

    def nAttrA(self):
        return len(self._attrA)  # do whatever is needed here...

    def nAttrB(self):
        return len(self._attrB)  # do whatever is needed here...

    def getAttrA(self, i):
        return self._attrA[i]  # do whatever is needed here...

    def getAttrB(self, i):
        return self._attrB[i]  # do whatever is needed here...
```

Comment: I butchered some of the naming since I built it matching the original code, then did some fast find/replace to remove the original naming. The actual code follows PEP8.
I will check this works for the actual source. I need it to use the getAttrA method since it is actually getting the values from the C++ function. I think this might be the right way to go is mask it with a property.

Comment: bloominonion: I see. Have update answer accordingly.

Comment: This looks like it will work after some testing. I will mark this as answered once I confirm it with the actual source at work tomorrow. I like doing it this way as well since it is reusable for any of my other classes with similar problems. Thanks for the help!

Comment: bloominonion: I've posted a second update to my answer which no longer requires using properties, and is better in other ways. See if you agree.

Comment: bloominonion: Made a few relatively minor additional changes (Edit #2.1).

Comment: I had to go back to a version of what you originally had. I think in general, you solution above is the best way to do it, but little did I know (since I haven't been re-mapping attributes) but SWIG also wraps the `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` functions. I will post mine as a separate answer for the sake of SWIG users, but I will mark yours as answer for general Python.

Comment: Disappointing. Even if you end up using my code in Edit #1, you should modify it to use the `SequenceProxy` class in the current answer instead of the `MyList` class in the first edit—to avoid some potential problems. Also, even if SWIG overloads `__getattr__`, seems like you could derive your own subclass of _that_ class that would call SWIG's version but only if the attribute `name` wasn't something it was interested handling (so whatever processing the SWIG version does would still be able to occur when needed).